# How to extract Word style information and cluster text accordingly when converting from DOCX to RST

Tags: pandoc

I have a Word document (docx) consisting of several hundred pages that I need to convert to reStructuredText.

This alone would not be a big issue, but after conversion it must still be possible to identify specific sections of the Word document. All these section have the Word style "databox" and each "databox" starts with the text "data". So far I have been able to extract the style information by using "docx+styles" as input format.

However, there are two problems:

1. The style information is not contained in the resulting RST file
2. Even though a "databox" consists of several lines, Pandoc handles each lines separately so that e.g. in the AST output or other output formats it is not possible to distinguish if an element belongs to the current, previous or following "databox"

My idea was now to create a LUA script that inserts additional "start" and "end" patterns in the final RST so that I can identify what parts are running text and what parts are "databox" styles.

However, after reading the documentation , tutorials etc. for several hours and playing around with Pandoc I have not advanced a little bit. I'm able to identify the single DIVs with "databox" style and to manipulate their content.

```
function Div(elem)
    if (elem.t == 'Div') and (elem.attributes['custom-style'] == "databox") then
        return pandoc.Plain("<databox>" .. pandoc.utils.stringify(elem.content))
    end
end
```

However, I'm not able to come up with something that lets me decide whether the current DIV is the start or end of a "databox" so that I can set the start or end pattern accordingly.

Can someone provide me some guidance how I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: Could you add a minimal docx file? That'd make it easier to come IP with a solution.